# z3 simplify to polynomial form

Tags: z3, polynomial-math, z3py

How can I use z3 to print a complex function of (x) in polynomial form ? The `simplify` function print something nasty:

```
-1/120*(-5 + x)*(-4 + x)*(-3 + x)*(-2 + x)*(-1 + x) +
1/12*x*(-5 + x)*(-4 + x)*(-3 + x)*(-2 + x) +
```

Comment: What would be your ideal output? (x-5)(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(9x+1)/120 ?

Comment: it's the polynomial form sum(a_i * x^i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using Z3Py

```
x = Real('x')
y = (-1/120)*(-5+x)*(-4+x)*(-3+x)*(-2+x)*(-1+x)
z = (1/12)*(-5+x)*(-4+x)*(-3+x)*(-2+x)
w = y + z
print simplify(simplify(w, som=True), mul_to_power=True)
```

and the corresponding output is

```
120 + -274*x + 225*x**2 + -85*x**3 + 15*x**4 + -1*x**5
```